# Get the actual ALSA period length used

Tags: alsa

One of the hardware parameters that can be configured for ALSA is the *period*: the interval between interrupts. You can indicate the range of values you want to use, using the [`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_time`](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#gaa2bc2a32d3971521064741a30e10c92f) function.

But how do you get the *actual* value it selected? ALSA has a [`pcm_hw_params_get_period_time`](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#ga71f5d43bf63dc7292b8b58f17acccf89) function, but that does not seem to tell you the actual value, but rather tells you whether the value is in a particular range.

Answer (score 0):

The `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_time()` function selects a single value; if it succeeds, you know the value.

If you have set an interval with the `_min`/`_max` function, or did not restrict the period size at all, the actual period size is chosen when you call `snd_pcm_hw_params()`. You can then read the period length from the `hw_params` object.

The `dir` parameters is used to indicate that the actual value is between two integers; it does not actually define an interval.